# HttpPost ActionResult in Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using partial pages within modal dialogues to handle various CRUD actions elsewhere on a website and it's working fine, I have done everything the same with the login (shown below), but the `HttpPost` actionresult in the controller is not getting hit and I'm not sure why.

Instead the `HttpGet` is being called.

What have I missed?

**Login partial**

```
@model Models.User
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btn-login').click(function () {
            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        });
        $('#btn-close').click(function () {
            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="login-container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {        
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="login-table">
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-sm">Login</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-close-btn" data-dissmiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Account Controller Login Action Methods**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return PartialView("Login");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Announcements");
}
```

Comment: `[AllowAnonymous]` on the POST method?

Comment: Add Login([FromBody] User model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks! Weirdly didn't need either on another login app but that sorted it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GET method is marked with `[AllowAnonymous]` suggesting your controller is marked with `[Authorize]`, which means that you POST method must also be marked with `[AllowAnonymous]` (the user is authorized until the code in this method is executed)

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(User model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Announcements");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in form attribute

```
@Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", , new { modal= Model }, FormMethod.Post)

//Login- action Name that has to be hit

//Home     - Controller name
```

Comment: The default action is to `POST` so this is wrong and will not help.